# Node.js - How to pass a stream from request to xml-stream

Tags: node.js, xml, stream

I'm trying to download a large XML file and parse it using `xml-stream` library. I'm using `request` to download the file and it's capable of streaming the content of the file. Ideally, I'd like to pass that stream directly to `xml-stream` and have it parsed. But I can't figure out how to connect those two.

Here is the code a have so far:

```
request('http://example.com/data.xml').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.xml'));
...
var stream = fs.createReadStream('data.xml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
```

Is it possible to connect them directly without a temp `data.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request()` returns a Readable stream, so just pass that return value to `XmlStream()`:

```
var xml = new XmlStream(request('http://example.com/data.xml'));
```